Why isn't my variable called someName not available right after it is set
Why is someName variable not available as soon as I set it, but it is in another job?
source:
steps:
- powershell: |
    $rsdate = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $testVar = "hello world - $rsdate"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName]$testVar"
    "some name: $(someName)"
    

- powershell: |
    try {
        "some name: $(someName)"
        "rs date will be blank here: $rsdate"

        if ("$(someName)" -like "*hello world*")
        {
            "dates equals - $(someName)"
        }  
        else
        {  
            write-error "test error"
        }

        dotnet --list-sdks
    }
    catch {
        throw
    }



By default, the variable will be available to downstream steps within the same job

TL;DR you cannot use the variable in the same task where it's being set. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.
More details
From About task.setvariable (emphasis mine):
When you add a variable with task.setvariable, the following tasks can use the variable using macro syntax $(myVar). The variable will only be available to tasks in the same job by default.
If you add the parameter isoutput, the syntax to call your variable
changes. See Set an output variable for use in the same job.
